# OKI MCD563 printer issue after OS update

Tags: drivers, printing

I have updated my Ubuntu from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS.

Now my printer is not working anymore.
I have tried to reinstall the driver but this lead to no success.

Do you think I have to install ubuntu completley new?

Thank you very much for helping in advance.

BR Norbert

Answer (score 0):

I had connected the printer via USB. The new driver is not working via USB.

Now the printer is connect with a network cable to my router.
This works fine :-)